# Outlook 2010: How to get a list of all appointments, including recurrences

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I was trying to list all appointments in the default folder, like so:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = outlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

List<Outlook.AppointmentItem> lst = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();

foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
{
    lst.Add(item);
}
```

This lists all the appointments, except the recurring appointments - it only lists the first ocurrence. Is there a way to add all recurrences to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`AppointmentItem.GetRecurrancePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.getrecurrencepattern.aspx) method (and [`RecurrencePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.aspx) type) off the appointment item, then you can iterate over them.

An example of getting a single occurrence can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184586.aspx):

```
private void CheckOccurrenceExample()
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = Application.Session.
        GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).
        Items.Find(
        "[Subject]='Recurring Appointment DaysOfWeekMask Example'")
        as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    if (appt != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern =
                appt.GetRecurrencePattern();
            Outlook.AppointmentItem singleAppt =
                pattern.GetOccurrence(DateTime.Parse(
                "7/21/2006 2:00 PM"))
                as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            if (singleAppt != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("7/21/2006 2:00 PM occurrence found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I iterate through the appointment? Do I have to specify the start date for each recurring appointment and call `GetOccurrence`?

Comment: @aperez: You will need to access the `StartTime`m `EndTime` & `Occurrances` properties of the `RecurrancePattern` object. Then you can iterate over it. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219965%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: @aperez: Interestingly, I also found the [IncludeRecurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220097%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property you may be able to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

**If you sort by start time**, you can then use the IncludeRecurrences property to get *all*  appointment items.  One word of caution - if you have recurring appointments that don't have an end, you'll get an infinite loop - so be sure and test for an end date.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220097(v=office.12).aspx